# Created concentric circular pattern illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to create something like this in illustrator. Need some help.

[image]

Comment: Very nice your answer. +1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a small circle and from the **Appearance Panel** select the fill and from the menu Effect  → Distort & Transform → Transform:

[image: Transform]

- Go to menu Object → Expand Appearance
- Press <kbd>R</kbd> to activate the **Rotate Tool** and holding
  <kbd>Alt</kbd> click at the small circle center
- At the pop up window type `360/24` then **Copy**

[image: rotate]

- Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> Win to transform again until get the whole object
- Change the colors alternately

[image]

Comment: My sincere compliments.